# What's the probability in a group of 8 people at least 2 people rolling the same number

Tags: probability, statistics, birthday

In a group of 8 people what are the chances of at least 2 people getting the same number if they're rolling from 1 to 99 on a uniform distribution?

I've tried working this out by finding out the probability of no one in the group getting the same number then taking that from 1.

My initial calculation was thus $$1 - (98 \times 97 \times 96 \times 95 \times 94\times 93\times 92)/99^7 = 0.252 (3sf)$$ which seems way too high.

The other way of solving this is to find the probability of exactly 1<x people rolling the same number then adding them together, in which I got 0.00821 (3 sf) which is way too small since the probability must be greater than 1/99.

The calculation being
$\sum_{i=1}^7 \frac{98!}{99^7 \times (91+i)!}$
Can someone point out where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a variant of the famous birthday problem, which has various answers on this site and on the Internet; you may want to do a quick search.

Let's focus on the simplicity of the solution. It is easiest to find the probability that the eight
people *avoid* getting matching numbers 1 through 99.
$$P(\mathrm{No\,Match}) = \frac{99}{99}\frac{98}{99}\cdots\frac{92}{99} = \frac{{}_{99}P_8}{99^8} =0.7481.$$
S0, the probability of at least one match is $1-0.7481 = 0.2519.$

```
prod(99:92)/99^8
[1] 0.7480746
```

In the actual birthday problem (ignoring leap years)
the issue arises that not all 365 days of the year may
be equally likely. One can check using actual birthday
frequencies in the US where the distribution being
simulated is not exactly uniform.

For your problem, a simulation of a million plays of the 8-person game can be done in R as shown below. With a million iterations one can expect 2 or 3 place accuracy; the result is $0.252\pm 0.001.$

Simulation also allows us to get the expected number of matches among the eight players (about $0.28).$

In the R code `u` is a vector of a million
numbers of uniquely different results among the eight players.

```
set.seed(2020)
u = replicate(10^6, length(unique(sample(1:99, 8, rep=T))))
mean(u < 8)
[1] 0.252049     # Aprx P(At least 1 match) = 0.2519
2*sd(u < 8)/1000
[1] 0.0008683789 # 95% marg of simulation error
mean(8-u)
[1] 0.277366
```

Comment: The method you follow was pretty much the same as mine just presented in a different way (finding the probability of no matches then substracting that from one) with the same answer as well. My main concern arised from the fact this seems incredibly high especially given this was based off a real situation where people I talked to had essentially followed this situation dozens if possibly hundreds of times and almost never see this occur and wanted to confirm that my calculation was correct or find out what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I upvoted your query.  I regard your query in a **very positive** light, because
you are (in effect) stretching your intuition.  I regard intuition as indispensable
in problems involving probability &/or combinatorics.

In your initial calculation, I am unfamiliar with your RHS terminology,
but your LHS expression is accurate.

Critiquing your alternate approach is challenging, because I have to
speculatively reverse-engineer your #'s.  I was **not** able to do this.
That is, I could not come to terms with your thinking.

However, although I do not regard this alternative
approach as to be preferred in this problem, I do think that it is
still **highly** educational to explore it.  So...

The first thing to consider is how you are going to express your sample space,
which normally becomes the *denominator* (D) of a fraction.  Then when you
compute the numerator (N), in a **manner consistent** with how you computed the
denominator, the answer becomes $(N/D).$

The easy way is to set $D = (99)^8,$ which **requires** than when computing $N$,
you construe **order** as important.  That is, assuming that the people get
a number in ascending order (i.e. Person-1 before Person-2), then
[Person-1 = 5, Person-2 = 20] must be counted separately from
[Person-1 = 20, Person-2 = 5].

The alternative method of setting $D$ is to accept the complexity that
order must not be deemed important.  I am going to reject this approach
out of hand, because setting $D = (99)^8$ is simple and foolproof, as long
as you are extremely careful when computing $N$.

When considering the different ways that a match occurred (i.e. computing
$N$), one of the
challenges is to avoid **over-counting**.  There are two ways to approach
this challenge.

(1) Inclusion-Exclusion : Given sets A, B, and letting |X| denote the
number of elements in set X, you have 
$|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|.$

(2) Partition the cases of matched numbers into mutually exclusive groups whose union
represents all pertinent cases.  The **mutual exclusivity** is critical for
avoiding over counting.

For this problem, I would rather *eat ground glass* than try (1) above,
so against the backdrop of $D = (99)^8,$ I am going for (2).

First of all, **totally ignoring** what the matching numbers are, in how many
**different** ways can at least two of the people have matching numbers?

I would identify the various ways into cases (i.e. each case is to
be a mutually exclusive group), be sure that I haven't omitted any cases,
be sure that each case is **mutually-exclusive** from all of the others,
and then count the # of elements in each case (i.e. each group).
Note that the counting method used must be consistent with
setting $D = (99)^8.$

Group (1): 
All 8 people had the same #. 
The # of ways is 99, since once the # to be matched is to be identified,
there is only one way that it can occur.

Group (2): 
7 people had the same #, and there was one *odd man out*. 
There are 8 ways of choosing the odd man out.
Here, it would be a serious mistake to assume that there are 
$\binom{99}{2}$ ways of choosing the pertinent numbers, 
because having 7 people match #50, and 1 person getting #49 is **different** 
from having 7 people match #49, and 1 person getting #50.

Therefore you have to 
compute the # ways of choosing the numbers to be selected as 
$99 \times 98$. 
This makes the # of **elements** in this group: 
$8 \times 99 \times 98.$

If pursued to conclusion, this answer would be very long.  One of the
challenges would be to precisely identify each of the groups.

If you represent the first two groups as (for example) 
Group 1 = (8), Group 2 = (7,1), 
Then (in my opinion) the next groups would be represented by 
Group 3 = (6,2), and Group 4 = (6,1,1).

Instead, as one last examination, I am going to explore the group
(4,2,2), because I think that it has educational value. 
There are $\binom{8}{4} \times \binom{4}{2} = \frac{8!}{4! \times 2! \times 2!} $ 
ways that the 8 people can be appropriately grouped into (4,2,2).

At this point it is essential to ask yourself some hard questions.
For example, in the above computation method, is the grouping of (for example)
the people into (1,2,3,4), (5,6), (7,8) over counted. 
I say **yes** it has been over counted.

The **easiest** way to see this, is that once people (1,2,3,4) are grouped together
person-5 may go with either person-6, person-7, or person-8.
Therefore, the correct enumeration is $\binom{8}{4} \times 3.$

Keeping in mind the backdrop of $D = (99)^8,$ it is clear
that there are 99 choices for the first #.  Then, the question becomes
are the further choices to be computed as $98 \times 97$, or 
$\frac{98 \times 97}{2}.$

Keeping in mind that the grouping of (1,2,3,4), (5,6), (7,8) 
has not been over counted, and keeping in mind that you are looking
for a counting method consistent with $D = (99)^8$, 
I regard $(98 \times 97)$ as correct.

The **easiest** way to see this is to pretend that #99 was assigned to 
the group (1,2,3,4). 
Then, **regardless** of who Person-5 is partnered with 
there are 98 choices for the number that is to be assigned 
to Person-5 and his partner.
Then, there are 97 choices for the number that 
is to be assigned to the final 2 people.

Thus, for the group (4,2,2), the computation should be 
$\binom{8}{4} \times 3 \times 99 \times 98 \times 97.$

I realize that I have (in effect) *dodged* your actual question.  I did
this only because, as I say, I could not reverse engineer your thinking.
Hopefully, this answer will show you the complexities involved.

**Addendum**

Response to Lunatic Flowers' comment of 2020-09-29, at about 10:30am PST

First of all, good thinking.  Your comment indicates that you attach
importance to the idea that the *cases* you identify must be mutually exclusive.
This leaves three challenges:

(1) 
In addition to the cases being mutually exclusive, they must also be *comprehensive*.
That means that any eventuality that could occur (such as 5 people getting one
number and 3 people getting a different number) must **also** be assigned a separate case.

(2) 
You must stick with a **single** idea for the sample space (i.e. denominator $= D$).
In this case, I somewhat arbitrarily chose $D = (99)^8$, simply because it is the
simplest way of defining the sample space.

(3) 
When enumerating the # of ways that a specific case can occur, you must be
extremely careful.  That is, once you chose a *strategy* for defining
your sample space, then for each **case** that you enumerate, you must ensure that
its enumeration is perfectly consistent with your strategy, re defining the
sample space.

---

Assume that you accept that $D = (99)^8.$

Assume that you are focusing on the specific case where exactly $x$ people
got the same #, and the other $(8-x)$ people each got a different number, so that of the numbers 1 through 99,
$[8 + 1 - x]$ of these numbers were
distributed.

To facililitate a precise enumeration, I would **pretend** that each person was
assigned a name-tag (i.e. Person-1, Person-2, ... Person-8).  I would then
assume that the specific #'s (re from 1 to 99) to be distributed would be assigned
as follows:

First, a number would be assigned to the group of $x$ people.

Then, with respect to the $(8-x)$ remaining people, the person with the *lowest*
name-tag (e.g Person-1, if he is not part of the group of $x$ people),
would then be assigned a number.  Following that, of the people that had (still) not
yet been assigned a number, the person with the *lowest* name-tag would then be
assigned a number, and so forth.

The idea is that if (for example) neither Person-7 nor Person-8 are part of the
matching group of $x$ people, the possibility of Person-7 being assigned #51 (for example)
and Person-8 being assigned #50 must be considered as distinct
when compared with the possibility of Person-7
being assigned #50 and Person-8 being assigned #51.

This approach would **guarantee** that the *numerator* for this specific case
would be enumerated in a manner consistent with the denominator of $D = (99)^8.$

With this in mind, there are $\binom{8}{x}$ ways of selecting $x$ people to
represent the group that had matching #'s.  Further, once this group is selected,
then one number must be assigned to this group, and the other $(8-x)$ people must
each be assigned a separate number.

Therefore, my enumeration of the numerator for this specific case is

$\displaystyle \binom{8}{x} \times \frac{99!}{\left(99 - [8 + 1 - x]\right)!}.$

As an example, when $x = 3,$ the enumeration is

$\displaystyle \binom{8}{3} \times 99 \times 98 \times 97 \times 96 \times 95 \times 94.$

Again, I am unable to grapple with how you enumerate this possibility.  I hope
that you are able to understand my formula for the numerator when $x=3$, and for
the general value of $x$.  Please leave further comments, if you have more
questions/challenges/disagreements.

Comment: As I said in my original post the second calculation was an attempt at finding the probability of exactly x people getting the same number, where x = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8}. As the first person to roll is always going to be the same as themselves and different to previous rolls we can ignore the 1/99 in the denominator. Since the probability of at least two people getting the same number is the sum of 2,3,4,...,8 people getting the same number. For x = 2:

Comment: $$\frac{1}{99} \times \frac{98 \times 97 \times ... \times 93}{99^6}$$

For x = 3

$$\frac{1}{99^2} \times \frac{98 \times 97 \times ... \times 94}{99^5}$$

Where as x = 8 would be $\frac{1}{99^7}$. As the number of successes increase the power of $\frac{1}{99}$ increases since there is only a 1/99 chance of getting the same number as the previous people, but for the non matching rolls you still have to calculate the probability of not getting that same number as before, then the next person not getting either of the previous two numbers, and so forth.

Comment: @LunaticFlower In my opinion, your 2nd approach is very problematic, because the cases that you are considering (i.e. x people getting the same number) are **not mutually exclusive**, and hence lead to over counting.  For example, if I am interpreting your algorithm correctly (please advise if I am mistaken) you will be **double-counting** (for example) 3 people having #98 and 5 people having #97.  Mutually exclusive grouping is (in my opinion) absolutely required to prevent over counting.  This explains the approach in my answer, re groupings of (8), (7,1), (6,2), (6,1,1),...(4,2,2),...

Comment: When I say "x people getting the same number" I mean "exactly x people" meaning that for example, if x was 2, two people would get the same number and the remaining 6 would have different numbers from the first two and eachother.

Comment: After some thought I have a better understanding what you've said and I'm wondering the opposite, have I **undercounted**? I'm not certain that instances where there is more than one number that has been repeated has been included. I'm confused how x people getting a match with another person **is not** mutually exclusive.

Comment: @LunaticFlower Please see the Addendum that I have just added to my answer.